# Mechanicalsoup is not working after rebuild computer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mechanicalsoup

I was forced to reinstall windows on my Computer. Since that, I have one problem after the other.

Right now. I have a problem with python or better mechanicalsoup. I have pythonscrips for webscrapibng which used to work completly fine. But now they do not work anymore.
At the beginning I could't even use "pip install 'Packagename'" anymore. I needed to use the long way (python -m install 'Packagename'). I managed to solve this issue.

I already uninstalled and installed mechanicalsoup, python and even visual codes.

I have absolute no idea where to look and how to solve this problem by now. Did I forgot to install something important ? Has anyone an idea what's the issue here ?

That's the code i'm using right now. From my understanding there is no issue with the code. As I already mention. It use to work 3 days ago.

```
 import mechanicalsoup
 
 # create stateful browser
 browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
 soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
 raise_on_404=True,
 user_agent='MyBot/0.1: mysite.example.com/bot_info',
 )

 # use browser to open link
 browser.open("https://stackoverflow.com/")

 # find and follow login link
 browser.follow_link("users/login")
```

The Error-Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Webscrapting_Test\sign_in.py", line 46, in <module>
    browser.follow_link("/users/12345678")

  File "C:\Users\dw.FROMMEDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", line 341, in follow_link
    link = self._find_link_internal(link, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\dw.FROMMEDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", line 317, in _find_link_internal

return self.find_link(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\dw.FROMMEDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", line 291, in find_link
    raise LinkNotFoundError()

mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError
```

Comment: After you update the system, have you tried to test this code in a system terminal outside of VS Code? (I want to know if this problem only occurs in VS Code.)

Comment: Hello Jill Cheng. Thank you for comment. I never thought of trying that. It is working when I use the terminal.

Comment: -Have you tried other python environments in VS Code? And have you tried to reinstall the required modules in the environment you are using? If it is convenient, please provide us with examples that can minimize the recurrence of this problem.

Comment: No. I used the Terminal of python itself. It is working there perfectly fine. I uninstalled mechanicalsoup and installed it again as well. This was one of my first steps. Unfortunatelly I'm a beginner in coding and I recently startet to use python and vs codes. So I don't even which information could be useful to you and where to find that. I think it has to do something with the path(windows advanced system settings). Because that's where I needed to go to get the pip command to work again. Since that it fells like it works differently. Btw. when I'm checking the version in windows console.

Comment: Windows can't find python. So I'm checking the version with this command: "python --version". The output says: "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings".

But when I use the command "where python". It shows me the path.

Comment: -Since in VS Code, its internal terminal integrates the terminal from the system, it is recommended that you try to run your code in the cmd terminal outside of VS Code to eliminate problems from the system and python installation or configuration.

Comment: That's what I tried and it is working without any problems in the terminal from the system. But what am I checking next ? 
I managed meanwhile to get the command "python --version" to run. but this didn't solve the problem for the VS Codes terminal.

Comment: -Did you also use python3 before? According to the information you provided, the problem occurred in "mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", it is recommended that you use the command "pip show mechanicalsoup" to find the module installation location, and then try to delete the module folder "mechanicalsoup", and then reinstall it to avoid The file is damaged or dependent.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot. Now it is working again. Thank you for your help day after day :) I hope I can give that back at some point as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you provided, the problem occurred in "`mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py`", it is recommended that you use the command "`pip show mechanicalsoup`" to find the module installation location, and then try to delete the module folder "`mechanicalsoup`", and then reinstall it to avoid The file is damaged or dependent.

[image]

[image]